# Redis Cluster error

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

redis.7001.conf

```
port 7001  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file nodes.conf  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

redis.7002.conf

```
port 7002  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file nodes.conf  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

redis.7003.conf

```
port 7003  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file nodes.conf  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

redis.7004.conf

```
port 7004  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file nodes.conf  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

redis.7005.conf

```
port 7005  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file nodes.conf  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

---

```
H:\Tools\cluster>ruby H:\Tools\cluster\redis.trib.rb create --replicas 0 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7004 127.0.0.1:7005
>>> Creating cluster
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7001: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7002: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7003: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7004: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7005: OK
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 5 nodes...
Using 5 masters:
127.0.0.1:7001
127.0.0.1:7002
127.0.0.1:7003
127.0.0.1:7004
127.0.0.1:7005
M: 6c5c8b20e7f051e19a41e96a1d0b37cc79abf647 127.0.0.1:7001
   slots:0-3276 (3277 slots) master
M: 6c5c8b20e7f051e19a41e96a1d0b37cc79abf647 127.0.0.1:7002
   slots:3277-6553 (3277 slots) master
M: 6c5c8b20e7f051e19a41e96a1d0b37cc79abf647 127.0.0.1:7003
   slots:6554-9829 (3276 slots) master
M: 6c5c8b20e7f051e19a41e96a1d0b37cc79abf647 127.0.0.1:7004
   slots:9830-13106 (3277 slots) master
M: 6c5c8b20e7f051e19a41e96a1d0b37cc79abf647 127.0.0.1:7005
   slots:13107-16383 (3277 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
>>> Nodes configuration updated
>>> Assign a different config epoch to each node
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster
Waiting for the cluster to join..........................................................................................................................................................
```

i use Redis-x64-2.8.2400.zip from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases

i tested many times.

why block  on 【Waiting for the cluster to join】?

please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exact the same problem. Just like you I had all the redis.{PORT}.conf files to have cluster-config-file to be the same, nodes.conf. After I changed them to have different files, nodes-{PORT}.conf, the problem went away.